# Comparison plots

Tags: r, plot

Hi I'm currently analysing some data from a bioassay that we did on pea aphids in the lab. We applied two different insecticides observe the LD50.

What I would like to do is create a plot that includes concentration (con) and have the data from both the leaf disk (ld) and the whole leaf (wl) on one plot so I can compare both sets of data. I am able to plot one at a time easily but really stumped on how both on one graph. I have looked at a lot of tutorials on line but I'm not finding anything that is helpful. I have included my data set below.

con         ld   wl
0.01        90%  19%
0.00316     47%  7%
0.001       24%  6%
0.000316    9%   8%

Thank you in advance

Debz.

Comment: please share a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are looking for something like this?

```
dat <- data.frame(con = c(0.01,0.00316,0.001,0.000316),
                  ld = c(90,47,24,9),
                  wl = c(19,7,6,8))

plot(dat$con, dat$ld, type="n", xlab="Concentration", ylab="Percent (%)")
lines(dat$con, dat$ld)
lines(dat$con, dat$wl, col="green")
```

[image]